# How to get specific value by using index

Tags: c++, caa

I want to extract my date that is "2017-11-10" value from this type of string
 "(D(2017-11-10)".

I am trying to directly hit the value starting from 2017 as I do not want
"(D("  in the final string but I don't know how can I do it.

I have tried like this

```
int date= istr.SearchSubString("D(");
```

but this searches only the starting part of "(D(2017-11-10)" which is ok

but now how can I get "2017-11-10" that is my date.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You have to show us your work.

Comment: eg. int date= istr.SearchSubString("D(");
        
       something like this but not sure how to go with this.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly to show what you have tried, what you expected to happen and what happened instead

Comment: I suggest... drum roll... regex...

Comment: what do u mean?

Comment: The C++ standard library regex: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex is the easiest solution:

```
std::string date = "(D(2017-10-11)";
std::regex dateRegex("(D(");
std::string newDate = std::regex_replace(date, dataRegex, ""); //This will replace the (D( with an empty string
```